# Permalink of Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, rewrite-rules

I am trying to create a custom post type called an 'event' and have it's permalink structure be as follows:

www.domain.com/events/238

where 238 is the post ID.  However, when I navigate to the page, I get a 'no results found' page.

Here is my code (I abbreviated the register_post_type call to include only the important elements).

```
add_action( 'init', 'initialize'));

function initialize() {
    register_post_type('event',
        array(
            'labels' => array('name' => 'Events'),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );

    global $wp_rewrite;

    $event_structure = '/events/%event_id%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%event_id%", '([0-9]+)', "event_id=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('event', $event_structure, false);
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'handle_permalink', 10, 3);

function handle_permalink( $permalink, $post_id, $leavename ) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    if ( $post->post_type == jp_event::POST_TYPE ) {
        $rewritecode = array( '%event_id%' );
        $rewritereplace = array($post->ID);
        $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
        return $permalink;
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

How do I make this code work?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try visiting the `Settings > Permalinks` screen in your admin area, and save your permalink structure (even if you make no changes to it).  This should flush your permalink structure.  See the note at http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules .

Comment: I just tried this and it still isn't working.  When I'm in the edit post page, the permalink is being displayed correctly under the title but when I click 'View Event' and it takes me to the page, it says no results found (and when I remove the custom permalink logic the page resolves fine so I'm pretty sure that it is this logic that is causing the issue).

Comment: Do you have a caching plugin? if so, flush the cache.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to set `'rewrite' => false` in your `register_post_type()` and then try to recreate the permalink in another function?  If not, try passing an array into the `rewrite` argument as detailed in [the Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Comment: I'm not really clear what you are suggestion - you think I should just put /events/%event_id% in as a parameter of 'rewrite'?  I just tried and it doesn't seem to be working -